# Unable to run sympy with a string contains double backslashes

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to convert a list of string into SymPy expression objects using the sympy.sympify() function. However, it doesn't take double backslashes.

May I know how to solve this?

```
list_of_strings = ['\\phi G \\rightarrow H', '\\phi ( A )', '\\alpha _ { 0 } , \\ldots , \\alpha _ { m - 1 } \\in F']

expr = sympy.sympify(list_of_strings[0])
```

```
ValueError: Error from parse_expr with transformed code: "\\Symbol ('phi' )Symbol ('G' ) \\Symbol ('rightarrow' )Symbol ('H' )"
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dennislau/Desktop/GoodNotes/Math/math_data_collection/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sympy/core/sympify.py", line 496, in sympify
    expr = parse_expr(a, local_dict=locals, transformations=transformations, evaluate=evaluate)
  File "/Users/dennislau/Desktop/GoodNotes/Math/math_data_collection/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sympy/parsing/sympy_parser.py", line 1101, in parse_expr
    raise e from ValueError(f"Error from parse_expr with transformed code: {code!r}")
  File "/Users/dennislau/Desktop/GoodNotes/Math/math_data_collection/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sympy/parsing/sympy_parser.py", line 1092, in parse_expr
    rv = eval_expr(code, local_dict, global_dict)
  File "/Users/dennislau/Desktop/GoodNotes/Math/math_data_collection/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sympy/parsing/sympy_parser.py", line 907, in eval_expr
    expr = eval(
  File "<string>", line 1
    \Symbol ('phi' )Symbol ('G' ) \Symbol ('rightarrow' )Symbol ('H' )
                                                                     ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/Users/dennislau/Desktop/GoodNotes/Math/math_data_collection/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sympy/core/sympify.py", line 498, in sympify
    raise SympifyError('could not parse %r' % a, exc)
sympy.core.sympify.SympifyError: Sympify of expression 'could not parse '\\phi G \\rightarrow H'' failed, because of exception being raised:
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character (<string>, line 1)
```

I tried replace the double backslahes into single backslash but still doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Part of the problem may be that these strings **do not actually** contain double backslashes; they contain single backslashes. It is important to understand that **the code you write to create a string, is not the same as the actual contents of the string**. Aside from that, please read [ask] and [mre]. Make sure - by **trying it yourself first** - that someone else could **copy and paste** the code from the question **without changing or adding anything** and see the **exact problem, directly**. That means, include any necessary `import`s etc.

Comment: Also, `sympify` does not read TeX. `sympy.sympify("phi(A)")` works; `sympy.sympify("\\phi(A)")` does not. You should read [the documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html?highlight=sympify#module-sympy.core.sympify) to see what `sympify` does, and what it does not do. (`phi` belongs under "any object defined in SymPy").